# PTIJ: What type of grapes is the Messiah buying? Why does he need them?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Pesikta Rabbati 36](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesikta_Rabbati.36.1?lang=bi):

> שנו רבותינו בשעה שמלך המשיח נגלה בא ועומד על הגג של בית המקדש והוא משמיע להם לישראל ואומר להם ענוים הגיע זמן גאולתכם
>
> Our Rabbis taught: 'When King Messiah is revealed, he will come and stand on the roof of the Temple, and announce to Israel, and he will say to them "Grapes! The time has come to [purchase](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Leviticus.25.33.1?lang=bi) you!"'

Why does the Messiah need to buy grapes? What type of grapes is he buying? And what does he intend to do with them?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Grapes! Humble grapes! Your time of disgust is here!

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Don’t forget to sing it to a stirring melody

Comment: @JoelK Someone actually did that (1:33 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yluROQBBRg&ab_channel=%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A grape is an essential fruit for anyone who hopes to be a king forever. Just look at King Saul, who made the fatal mistake of not bringing along a grape with him to the throne:

> וּבְנֵי בְלִיַּעַל אָמְרוּ מַה יֹּשִׁ עֵנוּ זֶה וַיִּבְזֻהוּ וְלֹא הֵבִיאוּ לוֹ מִנְחָה וַיְהִי כְּמַחֲרִישׁ
>
> Some jerks said, "What grape does this guy have?" So they despised him and didn't bring him a gift, and he was silent.<sup>1</sup> ([1 Samuel 10:27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.10.27))

No wonder his royal dynasty ended as soon as he died.

As Elihu points out,

> לֹֽא־יִגְרַ֥ע מִצַּדִּ֗יק עֵ֫ינָ֥יו וְאֶת־מְלָכִ֥ים לַכִּסֵּ֑א וַיֹּשִׁיבֵ֥ם לָ֝נֶ֗צַח וַיִּגְבָּֽהוּ׃
>
> A righteous man is never without a grape, and it accompanies kings to the throne, and it seats them forever and they rise. ([Job 36:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Iyyov.36.7))

When King Messiah is revealed, since he would like his kingship to last forever, he would naturally have to take along some grapes.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>His descendants in Shushan, though, figured out that there were four problems with how their ancestor had been treated: "(1) "What grape does this guy have?" (2) So they despised him and (3) didn't bring him a gift, and (4) he was silent." So they instituted a yearly holiday with four objectives: (1) to celebrate with grape products, (2) friendly food exchange, (3) gifts to the poor, (4) reading out loud a story in praise of grape products.</sub>

Comment: Kudos for the Purim-themed footnote. I chortled

Answer (score 7):

In answer to your first question, grapes play a very important factor in our avodas Hashem, as it says expressly in [Tehillim 10:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.10.17?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he):

> **תַּאֲוַ֬ת עֲנָוִ֣ים** שָׁמַ֣עְתָּ ה' תָּכִ֥ין לִ֝בָּ֗ם תַּקְשִׁ֥יב אָזְנֶֽךָ׃
>
> Hashem - You will listen to the **desire of grapes**, You will make their hearts firm; You will incline Your ear.

But what is it that makes grapes so important? It is because they contain more than just healthy goodness, they are imbued with an innate holiness. As it says in [Tehillim 25:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.25?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he)

> יַדְרֵ֣ךְ עֲ֭נָוִים בַּמִּשְׁפָּ֑ט וִֽילַמֵּ֖ד עֲנָוִ֣ים דַּרְכּֽוֹ׃
>
> He guides the grapes in the right path, and teaches the grapes His way.

Indeed, historically, those who imbibe the way of the grape are the natural leaders of klal yisroel. We famously say about Moshe Rabbeinu in [Bamidbar 12:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.12.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0)

> וְהָאִ֥ישׁ מֹשֶׁ֖ה ענו מְאֹ֑ד מִכֹּל֙ הָֽאָדָ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֖ר עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הָאֲדָמָֽה׃
>
> Now Moses was of a very grape-like personality, more so than any other man on earth.

So it stands to reason, as Hashem personally tends to the grapes, and their holy essence helped to shape undoubtedly the greatest Jewish leader in Moshe Rabbeinu,  it follows that the Messiah will have to purchase grapes to gain from this inherent Kedusha and be fitting to lead the Jewish people.

Once these grapes have been purchased he can effectively distribute them to the rest of the Jewish people so that they too embrace the heightened levels of Kedusha. As it says in [Tehillim 69:33](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.69.33?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he) and in [Tehillim 22:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.22?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he):

> רָא֣וּ עֲנָוִ֣ים יִשְׂמָ֑חוּ דֹּרְשֵׁ֥י אֱ֝לֹהִ֗ים וִיחִ֥י לְבַבְכֶֽם׃
>
> They will see grapes and they will be happy, you who are mindful of G-d, take heart!

> יֹאכְל֬וּ עֲנָוִ֨ים ׀ וְיִשְׂבָּ֗עוּ יְהַֽלְל֣וּ ה' דֹּ֣רְשָׁ֑יו יְחִ֖י לְבַבְכֶ֣ם לָעַֽד׃
>
> They will eat grapes and they will be satisfied. Let all who seek the LORD praise Him. Always be of good cheer!

Thus the Messiah will purchase grapes, gain from their G-dliness/goodliness and then share them with the rest of the Jewish people to usher in a time of much happiness and  good cheer. Those who do not partake of this grape-fest the [Talmud Yerushalmi Kiddushin 48b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kiddushin.48b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi) warns expressly:

> רבי חזקיה ר' כהן בשם רב עתיד אדם ליתן דין וחשבון על כל שראת עינו ולא אכל
>
> Rabbi Chizkiya, Rabbi Cohen in the name of Rav said, in the future (a reference to the times of Moshiach) a person will have to give judgment and accounting over every grape he saw and did not eat(!)

Comment: This answer is helpful.

Comment: Why thank you! Tis the season :-)

Answer (score 4):

The prophet stated that the messiah will be [riding on a donkey](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.9.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and therefore grapes will be needed for the donkey. As it says in the [blessings](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.32.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) of Haazinu,

> וְדַם־עֵנָ֖ב תִּשְׁתֶּה־חָֽמֶר
> "The donkey shall drink grape-blood."

This section foreshadow the future redemption: It says there in [Haazinu](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.32.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ה' **בָּדָ֣ד** יַנְחֶ֑נּוּ, in [Bil'am's blessing](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.23.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) הֶן־עָם֙ **לְבָדָ֣ד** יִשְׁכֹּ֔ן and in [Moshe's bracha](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.33.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) וַיִּשְׁכֹּן֩ יִשְׂרָאֵ֨ל בֶּ֤טַח **בָּדָד֙**.

I am assuming that the word "בד"/"בדד" refers to a wine press ("בית הבד"). Assuming wrongly.

Update: JoelK is suggesting that [Bereishis 49:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is relevant as well, and of course he is right.

Comment: If you were so inclined, you could probably work Bereishis 49:11 into this as well

Comment: @JoelK Oh, yeah, that's even better.

Comment: @JoelK I went to look for that in the answers before writing it up; oh well

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Al zeh ne’emar “the early donkey catches the grapes”. Or something like that anyway...

Answer (score 2):

The grapes are the people of Edom, whose punishment is described (Yeshayah 63:2-3ff) as Hashem treading out grapes. גאולתכם doesn't mean "your purchase," but "your filthiness" - the same root as is used in v. 3 there (וכל מלבושי אגאלתי).

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01830.html

> והוא סוד אשר חכמים הגידו על חוה שסחטה ענבים ונתנה לו, והכוונה הוא כי
> שורש של הדינים והגבורות הוא שם אלהים בבינה, ושני פעמים אלהים כמנין
> ענבים והדין קדוש אשר בתוכו הוא סוד יין המשומר בענביו

Since mashiach has to redeem the *middas ha'din*, he first has to buy that which has been created through the *middas ha'din*.

This is the *kavanah* of the *arichus* at the beginning of Avodah Zarah, e.g.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%91

> אמר להם הקב"ה במאי עסקתם אומרים לפניו רבש"ע הרבה שווקים תקנינו הרבה
> מרחצאות עשינו הרבה כסף וזהב הרבינו וכולם לא עשינו אלא בשביל ישראל כדי
> שיתעסקו בתורה אמר להם הקב"ה שוטים שבעולם כל מה שעשיתם לצורך עצמכם
> עשיתם תקנתם שווקים להושיב בהן זונות מרחצאות לעדן בהן עצמכם כסף וזהב
> שלי הוא שנאמר (חגי ב, ח) לי הכסף ולי הזהב נאם ה' צבאות כלום יש בכם
> מגיד זאת [שנאמר מי בכם יגיד זאת] ואין זאת אלא תורה שנאמר (דברים ד, מד)
> וזאת התורה אשר שם משה

Only once mashiach has been *koneh* the *shoresh ha'dinim* with which the *umos ha'olam* built *olam ha'zeh*, can he be the *shliach* to bring the *tikkun ha'shalem*.

*BIMHERA BEYAMENU AMEN!!!*